# How can I assign zero-counts for non-existent entries in a record (mySQL 5.6)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how many product_ids per material per type, using the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A` (
  `Product_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Material` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Product_id`,`Material`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `A` (`Product_id`, `Material`, `Type`) VALUES
  ('123', 'Mahogany', 'Chair'),
  ('123', 'Oak', 'Chair'),
  ('123', 'Birch', 'Chair'),
  ('456', 'Mahogany', 'Table'),
  ('456', 'Oak', 'Table'),
  ('789', 'Steel', 'Fridge'),
  ('789', 'Iron', 'Fridge'),
  ('111', 'Spruce', 'Chair'),
  ('111', 'Mahogany', 'Chair'),
  ('222', 'Mahogany', 'Table');
```

The end-result should look like:

| Type | Material | Product_id_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | Mahogany | 2 |
| Table | Mahogany | 2 |
| Fridge | Mahogany | 0 |

etc.

In other words, I need to not only count the id per type per material, I also need to assign 0 values to records that are not captured.

I really don't know how to handle this problem; I thought maybe I could do a Cartesian Product/cross-join and then group by Type and Material.

This is the best I could come up with:

```
select
   B.Material,
   B.Product_Count,
   C.Type
   from
   
   (select
      distinct Type
      from A) C
      
      Cross join 
      
  (select
   Material,
   Type,
   Count(Product_id) as Product_Count
    from A
    group by Material, Type) B
    
   on B.Type = C.Type
    group by B.Material, C.Type;
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a calendar table approach:

```sql
SELECT
    t.Type,
    m.Material,
    COUNT(a.Product_id) AS Product_id_count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM A) t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Material FROM A) m
LEFT JOIN A a
    ON a.Type = t.Type AND
       a.Material = m.Material
GROUP BY
    t.Type,
    m.Material;
```

The strategy here is to generate an intermediate table of all types and material using the cross join shown above.  We then left join this to your current `A` table and aggregate to get the counts.  Type-material combinations not having any data would receive a count of zero.

Note that more typically, you might maintain separate bona-fide tables for the types and materials.  In the absence of this, we can use the cross join approach above.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I was racking my brain for a while trying to figure this out.

Comment: Is there a way of achieving Cartesian Products in MySQL without explicitly using a Cross Join?

Comment: @K.Doe2 Not really.  In MySQL, we _could_ actually just write `INNER JOIN` here without an `ON` clause, but the implementation would be the same.